# How to launch 10 browser instances using Selenium Grid in the same machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I'm trying to launch 10 browser instances (IE) in a virtual machine and execute same script 10 times parallelly on those browsers. I updated the IE node to have

```
maxInstances=10" -maxSession 10
```

and code snippet from XML file is shown below,

```
<suite name="Automation" verbose="3" parallel="tests"
thread-count="500" preserve-order="true">

<test name="IMM_Test_IExplore" thread-count="1"  parallel="true"
        preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="iexplorer_windows"></parameter>
<classes>
    <class name="com.imm.testscripts.test1">
    <methods>
    <include name="test123"></include>
    </methods>
    </class>
    </classes>
```

My issue is, it's launching maximum 2 browser instances at a time and if I update maxInstances variable in IE node more than 3, It will launch only one instances.

Comment: suite name="Automation" verbose="3" parallel="tests"
 thread-count="500" preserve-order="true">

<test name="IMM_Test_IExplore" thread-count="1"  parallel="true"
  preserve-order="true">
  <parameter name="browserName" value="iexplorer_windows"></parameter>
<classes>
 <class name="com.imm.testscripts.test1">
 <methods>
 <include name="test123"></include>
 </methods>
 </class>
 </classes>

Comment: I updated question to show the HTML